# Extension vs non-extension method accessibility across classes

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I recently realized that an extension method is accessible even when it is declared in a class other than the class from which it is called. At the same type any other publicly accessible non-extension methods that are called across classes need to be qualified by a parent class name.

It’s the first time I realized it, and I can’t seem to find the formal reason / explaination for this seemingly inconsistent behavior. I am willing to accept it as it is, but is there some sort of a formal rule that describes and explains it?

If it is any use, here are two examples, first one displaying how an extension method can be called across classes and the second one displaying how a non-extension method can not be accessed across classes when not qualified with the parent class name prefix.

For the first example, see this https://dotnetfiddle.net/6yTSLV , where a Substring() extension method that lies within a public “Helper” class is called by a StringBuilder object in Program class. As a result of this extension method’s execution, a “HELLO WORLD” string is reduced to “HELLO” and displayed on the console.

For the second example, see this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xr2lvc , which throws an exception because a “MakeUpper(string entryString)” method can not be accessed when not qualified with the class name (obviously).

I hope that this question is not stupid.

Comment: That why they are called extension methods, the compiler treats them specially.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler encounters a method called on an instance of a type that doesn't have a corresponding member, it will look through all accessible types for an extension method with a corresponding signature and, if it finds one, it will assume that that is the method the code is referring to.

"Accessible type" means any type in the current assembly or a referenced assembly that is a member of the current namespace or whose namespace is imported in the current context. That second condition narrows down the search the compiler has to perform. If you haven't imported the namespace containing the type containing the extension method then you can't use the extension method.